# Text Input prompt

Tags: react-native

What is the area above the keyboard called? I am not seeing the suggested words. What is the prop called that makes me add suggested words?

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: I don't think this is a react-native thing that can be controlled with props. Are you on an iOS simulator?

Comment: @Dominic no this is a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area above the keyboard in a React Native app is called the "input accessory view". This is a customizable view that appears on top of the keyboard and can be used to add additional controls or information related to the input field.

To add suggested words to the input accessory view, you can use the TextInput component's inputAccessoryViewID prop along with a separate View component to define the contents of the input accessory view.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, InputAccessoryView } from 'react-native';

const ExampleTextInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
        inputAccessoryViewID="suggestions" // Add this prop to link to the input accessory view
      />
      <InputAccessoryView nativeID="suggestions">
        {/* Add your suggested words or any other content here */}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

In this example, we use the TextInput component's inputAccessoryViewID prop to link to a separate View component with the nativeID prop set to "suggestions". This creates an input accessory view with the ID "suggestions" that will appear above the keyboard when the TextInput is focused.

You can then add any content you like inside the View component to provide suggested words or other controls related to the input field. For example, you could use a FlatList component to display a list of suggested words that the user can tap to complete their input.

Note that the appearance and behavior of the input accessory view may vary depending on the platform and keyboard being used, so it's a good idea to test your implementation on a few different devices to ensure a consistent user experience.